# How to write Dahdi extra module from beginning?

Tags: linux, hardware, asterisk, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to port Asterisk into an armed linux operating system (particularly beagleboneblack). 
I'm partly done, but when I tried to cross compile DAHDI (or direct compile with `build-essential` installed on BBB's ) to communicate my BBB with FXO Card, I figured out that there are some modules (`wctdm,wcfxo, ...`) can not be built as usual, though  wctdm.c, wcfxo.c exists in dahdi's origin source code
I refer switchfin source code which is built for blackfined linux system, I see that they have some dahdi extra modules like `sport_interface bfsi ...` which is built with DAHDI_MODULES_EXTRA option at make time, and these extra module work for their blackfin board.
So I'm wondering where to get these extra module which work for my BBB, particularly help me to connect my BBB to FXO Card.
 If they don't already exists, which knowledge do I need to get started writing a new one? Unfortunately, I'm an software engineer and I'm not so familiar with Hardware design, so if it relates to Hardware design, well, I'm willing to learn.
Any help or explain will be appreciated
Best Regard
Loi Dang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no database of such firmwares.

You have only general option - search via google or other search engine.

For start with dahdi module creation you need basic kernel module experience, alot of c/c++ experience.

Best availible source - read files in dahdi-linux package source. Sorry, no better way at current moment.

Comment: Well thank @arheops soo much. I think I have a lot of things to do from now on.